# Login to website with a proxy

Tags: c#, .net, proxy

so I've been trying to create a C# application that can log into a specific website, however this website will reject the login if its not done through a korean proxy.

I don't really mind if its either webrequest or webbrowser but I am slightly more familiar with the WebBrowser control.

```
public static void remoteAuth() {
    string usr = Properties.Settings.Default.username;
    string pass = Properties.Settings.Default.password;

    currentUri = new Uri(@"https://logins.daum.net/accounts/loginform.do?url=http%3A%2F%2Fblack.game.daum.net%2Fblack%2Findex.daum");
    HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://logins.daum.net/accounts/loginform.do?url=http%3A%2F%2Fblack.game.daum.net%2Fblack%2Findex.daum");
    WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy("IP:PORT");
    myRequest.Proxy = myProxy;

    HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();

    webBrowser.DocumentStream = myResponse.GetResponseStream();

    webBrowser.Navigating += new WebBrowserNavigatingEventHandler(webBrowser_Navigating);

    remoteAuth();
}

private static void webBrowser_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Url.AbsolutePath != "blank") {
        currentUri = new Uri(currentUri, e.Url.AbsolutePath);
        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(currentUri);

        HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();

        webBrowser.DocumentStream = myResponse.GetResponseStream();
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

This is something I tried out earlier, I replaced the proxy with "IP:PORT" as a placeholder.

My code is kinda of a mess at the moment however I felt as if it was better to share something rather than just submit an empty question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the question? What's the outcome of running your current code? Meanwhile, check the documentation for the `WebProxy` object here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-enable-a-webrequest-to-use-a-proxy-to-communicate-with-the-internet

Comment: Sorry maybe I was unclear with my question, I'm looking to programatically connect to the website url above, fill in the username&password fields and hit connect all while under a proxy. From what I've read it seems as if the WebBrowser component is not really compatible with proxies, and I can't find much information regarding doing this with HTTPrequests.

Comment: What I need to be done in detail:

1. Connect to a set proxy.

2. Connect to "https://logins.daum.net/accounts/loginform.do?url=http%3A%2F%2Fblack.game.daum.net%2Fblack%2Findex.daum"  programmatically.

3. Send username&password from strings to the login fields "id" and "inputPwd".

4.  Send input to click the login button.

5. Navigate to another page of the site while still remaining logged in.

Comment: Are the credentials for the proxy or for the destination website? If the proxy is anonymous, setting a `WebProxy` object to `http://url.of.proxy:port` should make it transparent to the rest of your code.

Comment: The credentials are for the website itself, the proxy has no need for authentication. I'll look into your answer, thanks!